# Alpine Linux: See errors from apk add/del

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

`apk add`/`del` is reporting errors after any operation. It's always 2 errors. For example (`coreutils` is already installed):

```
$ sudo apk add -vv coreutils
After this operation, 0 KiB of additional disk space will be used.
2 errors; 3182 MiB in 839 packages

$ echo $?
2
```

The correct output should be `OK: 3182 MiB in 839 packages`.

Is there any way to fix this — or, at the very least, get more detailed error info? There's nothing in `/var/log/messages`, and I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

If it helps, I checked the source code and the errors are being printed in [`src/commit.c:358`](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/apk-tools/blob/master/src/commit.c#L358)... Seems to be related to a database issue of some sort?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `apk fix` ? I am pretty sure that it is not problem with `coreutils` then rather is a problem with some other package you've installed previously.

Comment: @fugitive Yep that fixed it -- added it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [fugitive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/126666/fugitive) and _ikke_ on IRC, `apk fix` resolved the issue automagically